# Ubuntu OS gets lost in dual boot another one is Windows 8.

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have windows 8 install in my primary drive and I have started to install ubuntu on my next drive. I am new to ubuntu family. All thing were going right as I was using both my OS. I was also studying on how to operate with ubuntu. Suddenly when I start my laptop the OS choose option is not available after that I have checked the Boot sequence order and there is no any sign of ubuntu. Later on I have check the drive from the windows 8 but it says to format the drive. Previously when I clicked on format then it shows the error message but now when I clicked it formatted the drive where I have install Ubuntu. So I am wondering where does Ubuntu OS have gone.

Comment: are you saying you have formatted the partition with Ubuntu?

Comment: Primarily there was Windows 8 installed and on next drive I have installed Ubuntu. When I restarted there was no any sign of Ubuntu even the drive where I have installed Ubuntu was asking for format when accessing from Windows 8.

Comment: You cannot access Linux partitions from Windows (unless you install drivers for accessing them). It will only show the options to format the drive. If you've formatted the drive, then you have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there any way that i could recover my excel and word files as they are important to me ???

Answer (score 0):

If you think you might have formatted the drive, create a Ubuntu pendrive using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and "Try Ubuntu Without installation". Mount the drive and check for any files.

If the files are intact, use this [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) to rescue GRUB from a live USB.

Comment: I have saved the files in the Ubuntu home folder that was important to me,  Is there any way that I could recover those file ???

Comment: Are you sure you formatted the drive?

Comment: Yup! previous it shows the error message but now when I clicked on format It formatted the drive. I have excel and word file in the home folder of Ubuntu OS. how could i recover it.

Comment: Try this tutorial---> http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/recover-deleted-data-using-photorec-in.html

Make sure you do not write any new data into the drive as it may overwrite previous data. Use Live USB if possible and use any other drive in the HDD to save the recovered data.

Comment: Was the tutorial useful? Did you recover the data you needed?